# ajax pager on views page load by ajax

Tags: ajax, drupal, view, pager

I load a vieschs views_embed_vesch using Ajax.
This views included  Ajax PAGER. It does not work.
Drupal.attachBehaviors does not work too.
I think in Drupal.settings need added data from views.

```
(function($){
 Drupal.behaviors.ajax_views = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
        //alert('dddd');
        $('a.views-link').click(function(){
           // alert('sfsdfsd')
          var relArr = $(this).attr('rel').split(' ');

          $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: Drupal.settings.basePath + 'ajax-views/'+relArr[0]+'/'+relArr[1],
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function (datad){
            alert(datad.seet.views);
          //  Drupal.settings.views = datad.seet.views ;              

             $('div#block-system-main > div.content').append(datad.view);

          },           
        });   
        return false;
        });     
}
```

};
})(jQuery);

Answer (score 0):

Try this module to load content via ajax. It will automatically attach behaviour with the ajax loaded content.

https://drupal.org/project/ajax_links_api